# How to understand which red bar is related to which leaked block in Instruments?

Tags: memory-leaks, instruments

I'm trying to understand locating leaked memory using Xcode4 and Instruments but I'm stuck at some point. I started recording the application and Instruments gathered the leaked memory.

So ok, I see the leaked blocks in the lower pane, but how can I understand which leaked block is related to which red bar? I assume that although all the blue bars indicate leaks, reds are the one that need real attention and so I want to know which block causes the red spike. I cannot click on a red bar to get further information about it. When I click on somewhere on the upper pane, all I got is a dashed line.

Need your directions, please.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found something: By clicking on somewhere on Leaks line, and then by pressing the left / right range buttons above Inspection Range (at the top) I can set the beginning and the ending of the range. That works like some kind of a filter on the leaked blocks.

Any clearer method is appreciated though..